# Xcode6.3 Deployment Target error

Tags: ios, xcode, deployment-target

I've set my project's Deployment Target to 7.0

Xcode still pop out this error message

[image]

[image]

It happen after I upgrade Xcode to version 6.3

What did I miss setting?

Comment: Make sure the Test target (xctest) has the same deployment target ( 7.0 ) as the main build target

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally there are 2 build targets by default in Xcode projects, one is the main build target while the other is the Test Target.

In your case, make sure both Deployment Target is set to 7.0.